# How can I Set wait_timeout for a Spesific Database on MySQL?

Tags: 18.04, mysql, connection, mariadb

I am setting a global wait_timeout value on my.cnf file but I want to set different wait_timeout values to different databases and it must not be in software side, I need to make it on MySQL service properties. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible. Please elaborate on what you need to do. For starters, what are "service properties"? There are some _statement_ timeouts available in MariaDB (but not MySQL); might that help?

Comment: may be an example can be more understantable. I have three applications that are always running and are connected to the database(MariaDB). I need to make configurations for these applications so the wait_timeout must be 1000 for app1, 2000 for app2 and 3000 for app3. Can I make that? I know it is possible to make on the application side but is it possible to make it on database side?

Comment: What do you want to happen after the timeout?

Comment: The application must be disconnected

Comment: And... Why?  To lessen the load on the system?  To make them go away?  Something else?

Comment: Some applications needs 3 minutes to make operations and close connections, some of them needs 30 minutes. It is a matter to gave 30 minute waitout for all applications when they don't close their connections. There are softwares that don't close their connections and it causes to fulling the connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how webpages are "stateless" and carry nothing from one page to the next, at least not in the same way as your program seems to do.  You are trying to keep a program up for 30 minutes with "state" not going away.

Even in this relatively reliable era, that is not practical.  It is better to do what web pages do and what queue processing does for long-running tasks -- Store the "state" somewhere (a database table) and hand off an "id" from one page to the next.  In a webpage, the "id" could be an argument in the URL or a value in a "cookie", etc.  Meanwhile, an arbitrarily large amount of data can be persisted in the database until the user comes back for it.

As for choosing between 3 minutes and 30, that would need to be done programmatically.

So...

1. Do what you can with the processing.
2. Store the "state" in a database, getting back an "id", which you give to the user.
3. Close the connection.

Later...

1. The user starts up the next stage of the processing
2. The id is used to fetch the state.
3. If he took too long (more than 3 or 30 minutes, as checked by your app), he is slapped on the wrist and sent away.

This drastically reduces the number of *simultaneous* connections needed.  Yes, there is some overhead of making a new connection, but this is worth it.  Also, you are in full control of how long he can "keep the cart active" or whatever.

"Safe" -- It can be argued that to pass a simple "id" number via the URL is very unsafe, especially from mischief-makers.  A hash can be used to greatly decrease the chance of such a hacker hitting on a valid id.  In web processing, a "cookie" is quite "safe".

Sorry for the hand-waving, but it would help to know something about your app (shopping cart, or queue, etc) and platform (website, etc).